# CRC user's guide for file compare

Tags: linux, crc

Can someone point me to a CRC user's guide for file compare?

I have a requirement to use CRC to compare and confirm two files match.  I have reviewed this site for how to use to use CRC with no real luck.

I have also looked for a CRC user's guide for file compare with no luck.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) has a description or how to calculate CRCs. And many other descriptions are a simple search away. If none of those meet your needs then you need to explain why and ask a more specific question.

Comment: But are you sure that you are required to use CRCs for file matching? CRCs are usually used for data integrity checks and not data matching. MD5 or similar hashes are more common for data matching.

Comment: Hello kaylum and thank you for the reply.  

I have never used CRC, but I have been told CRC will somehow outputs a number for each file.  If the number from both files are the same the files match.

I’m assuming at the moment CRC is some utility I can execute at the Linux command line.  Am wrong?  Your thoughts?

Comment: CRC and hash are a bit different different. I think you better go back and clarify what it is you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compute the CRC on file 1. You compute the CRC on file 2. If the CRCs are *not* the same, then the files are different. If the CRCs *are* the same, then the files *might* also be the same. There is no assurance that the files are actually the same, unless you compare them directly.

You can get a pretty high probabilistic assurance that two files are the same if you use a long cryptographic hash, such as SHA-256. That gives you both a very low probability that two different files accidentally have the same SHA-256 (2<sup>–256</sup> ~= 10<sup>–77</sup>), and it is considered to be not possible to modify a file to match the SHA-256 of another, different file. A CRC on the other hand is quite easy to spoof by someone who wants to fool you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the summation.  This is very useful, as it support my notion that the two files have to compared to grantee they are indeed the same.  Do you happen to know what the command is for computing the CRC on a file?  I'm just trying to close the loop on CRC.  Thanks much.

Comment: @tbtcust - it should be noted, that assuming there's enough space, it would be faster to read both files in and compare them. However, if the CRC | SHA-256 was pre-computed and stored for a file (or a set of CRC | SHA-256 for a set of files), then the verify process would only need to read in the test file and compute CRC | SHA-256 to check if the test file matches the original file that the CRC | SHA-256 was generated for. As Mark Adler pointed out using SHA-256 to check for modified files would be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'll give it a try.